# How can I stop VS from giving me several types of "System.OutofmemoryException" errors?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, out-of-memory

So, I've got Visual Studio 2010 and am working on a Silverlight 4 project. Recently, my dear VS started to, randomly by the way, **not build** due do an out of memory error.
I've had several types of errors:

- the famous "xap packaging failed"
- a simple System.OutofmemoryException
- etc

The answers, if one can call them so, that I keep finding are: restart your Visual Studio and it's all ok! Well... when I have to restart VS about 10 or 15 times a day, you can see where this can be troublesome right?

Does anyone know of a solution? I could try reinstalling the whole deal (VS, Silverlight Runtime, etc) but it would be preferable if there was an easier solution to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When the xap packaging does occasionally succeed how big is it?  How big is the largest resource that gets added to the dll or xap content?

Comment: What is your system spec? RAM?

Comment: It's not the RAM, cause I've got 4Gbs of it... the xap packaging when it succeeds is 2.3 Mbs big, which is not much cause I've had much bigger projects without any issues. Since this is happening only with the latest versions of silverlight runtime and tools and toolkit and VS 2010, I thought it might be some issue with this. 
Or maybe Is there some memory limit defined in VS for this type of builds?

Comment: Let me know if you find a solution!  I simply accept that I have to restart VS2010 approx three times a day!  It seems that the longer I have my SL solutions open the more chance I have of getting a System.OutofmemoryException error during a build.  I'm sure VS2010 leaks memory.

Comment: We have had that error and found it vanished after a reinstall of all the additional tools and SDKs we had installed (and made sure we installed the latest VS service packs *before* reinstalling any add-ins)

Comment: Did someone find a solution to this? For me it works sometimes by cleaning the solution and rebuilding it but mostly have to restart

Answer (score 1):

Try,

1. "iisreset"
   or
2. Clean the temp files in the path "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files"

Comment: The question is about compiling the code, not running the application.

Comment: @ChrisF: Ya u r right. What, if u have a hosting web project associated with it?